# Possible to hide POIs on Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have embedded Google Maps v2 in my app. There are a lot of POIs like restaurants and parks on the map, which I want to have removed. I am talking about things like "Google Bldg 44" on the lef image below and "Charleston Park" on the right image below:

[image]

Does anybody know a way to hide these points? It seems to be possible in the [Google Maps JavaScript Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/styling-the-base-map?hl=en#hiding_features) but I found nothing in the Google Maps Android SDK documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with the Google Maps Android API v2, but it has been requested in a [gmaps-api-issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4841). It is indeed possible in the javascript API, and it is also possible to develop a [javascript version for mobile devices](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Mobile). This does not solve the issue for native Android apps, but it is a way of [getting it done](http://android-er.blogspot.nl/2013/06/embed-html-using-google-maps-javascript.html).